# How should I interpret “Be different like that”?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality

> Be different like that!

What does it mean? Is it grammatically correct? I don't think it has any problems, but I am not sure.

Comment: It could mean a number of things, but unless you provide us with context, no one will be able to say definitively.

Comment: (She is different from other girls in attitude, behavior) which one like. So he tells her to be different like that always.

Comment: Where have you heard or seen that? Can you give a link?

Comment: It's my own statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fairness it can't actually be fully understood without context.

'*that!*' refers to a prior thought, perhaps the previous sentence, one assumes it will be some kind of message emphasing individuality (that is difference). The phrase '*Be different like that!*' thus acts to summarise and reinforce that which has already been said.

Breaking it down, '*be*', acts as the imperative, that is a command. Indeed the exclamation (!) recognises that we're speaking in the imperative, and serves to lighten the tone. In this way, it's not a forceful command, it's guiding and light. Cheeky perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

It is a command (because 'be' is in the [imperative mood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_mood)) to be different, just as 'that' (what 'that' is depends on the context) is different.
Different would mean here 'not ordinary, not common' (see [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/different)).

I agree that it sounds a little weird, though.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two meanings...

> "Be different like that (person is different)!"

I would say this to you if we are observing a person that is different than our shared expectations, and I think you should be different in the same way that person is different.

> You: "I don't like donuts" Me: "Be different like that!"

I would say this to you if your statement/behavior contradicts my expectations.  This is intended to convey my recognition (and possibly frustration) of this difference.